# Jenkins Pipeline push Docker image

Tags: jenkins, docker, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins job is Pipeline that running in Dockers:

```
node('docker') {
  //Git checkout           
  git url: 'ssh://blah.blah:29411/test.git'

  //Build
  sh 'make'

  //Verify/Run
  sh './runme'
}
```

I'm working with kernel and my sources take a lot of time to get it from GIT (it's about 2GB). I'm looking on how I can push the docker image to use it for the next build so it will already contain most of the sources. I probably need to do:

```
docker push blahdockergit.blah/myjenkinsslaveimage
```

but it should run outside of the container.

Comment: What part of the build process do you want to speed up? Where are you building your docker image?

Comment: My docker image is stored locally, I'm trying to speed up getting files from git (for now it takes around 10 minutes) when running inside the jenkins slave docker containter.

Comment: Does this huge amount of data you pull from git ever change?

Comment: No, the changes are very small

Comment: Are all these changes in the same folder?

Comment: Not exactly, but I don't see how it's related, but to simplify the subject, let's say "yes, all in same folder"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in pipeline syntax that following class can be used for building external jobs

[image]

Comment: At the end I finished with pushing docker image running on docker host machine, I mean outside the docker container.